# Post a form in jQuery when this form is loaded in AJAX with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I want to post a form using jQuery.post :

JS function:

```
function post_ajax_form2(url,formId,message){   
  bsendMessage = 0; 
  if (typeof message !== 'undefined') { bsendMessage =  1;} 
  var data = jQuery('#'+formId).serialize();    
  alert(data);
  jQuery.post(url,data);    
  if (bsendMessage == 1) { alert(message); }
}
```

The form is loaded in AJAX using a single jQuery.load.

HTML form loaded:

```
<form action="index.cfm" method="get" id="fdesc_preview">
   <input type="hidden" name="change_preview" value="1">
   <input type="checkbox" id="cbpreview" name="PREVIEW" class="preview" value="1" onclick="post_ajax_form2('myUrl.html','fdesc_preview');" <cfif attributes.preview> checked</cfif>></td>
   <td>Show short descriptions&nbsp;</td>
</form>
```

When I click on the checkbox the form is posted, but the data are empty.
The same code on a single HTML page work.

I'm missing something ?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Is there only one copy of the form loaded with Ajax? (If you have multiple with the same id that would explain the problem.) What does the `alert(data)` show? Is that all of your html for the form? If so, why do you have an orphan `<td>` element?

Comment: Use the change event so that you can be sure that the value has changed when your code runs.

Comment: @nnnnnn There is only one copy of the form loaded in Ajax and I copy only a part of the HTML code. The alert(data) is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution (and the reason) of the empty serialize :

The form is located into a `<table><tr><td>` ... and a `<form>` element is not allowed as a child of `<table>`.

The browser was correcting the error by moving it outside the table and closing the `</form>` just after it start , which would mean that the  elements are no longer inside it: the serialized data are then empty !

My source code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" align="left">
  <tr>
    <form action="index.cfm" method="post" id="fdesc_exp_view" name="fdesc_exp_view">
      <td width="16">
        ......
        <input type="checkbox" id="cbexpanded_view" name="expanded_view" class="expanded_view" value="1" onchange="post_ajax_form('myUrl','fdesc_exp_view','thanks 2');"<cfif attributes.expanded_view> checked</cfif>>
      </td>
       <td>Show expanded view&nbsp;</td>
     </form>
   </tr>
```

The browser output source code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" align="left">
<tbody>
  <tr valign="middle">
    <form id="fdesc_exp_view" name="fdesc_exp_view" method="post" action="index.cfm"></form>  
    <td width="16">
      .......
      <input id="cbexpanded_view" class="expanded_view" type="checkbox" onchange="post_ajax_form('myUrl','fdesc_exp_view','thanks 2');" value="1" name="expanded_view">
    </td>
    <td>Show expanded view </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The same code works if the page is not loaded in AJAX, to be sure that it will work always I simply put the form outside the table and have now data in my post.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

with this form of your post:

```
jQuery.post(url,data);    
if (bsendMessage == 1) { alert(message); }
```

the IF condition statement executes immediately, NOT waiting for the post to return - the post is asynchronous and needs to have that if condition in the callback function for the  post.

Example of change:

```
jQuery.post(url,data).done(function(message) {
    alert(message); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your remark, the message was just here to inform the user (like: thanks),I will adapt the fct.